# Syncing of Two Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I have problems syncing two databases using replication.

Yes, I've done the part where it can copy `SERVER A`'s data to `SERVER B`.

But my problem is, it deletes the existing data of `SERVER B` that is not found in `SERVER A`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Then you should add a `sql-server-2008-r2` tag to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  Each type of replication in SQL Server typically begins with an initial synchronization of the published objects, which is known as the *snapshot*.  The snapshot is a copy of all of the published objects and data specified by a publication (the source).  This is covered in [Types of Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx).

By default, the article property **Action if name is in use** (@pre_creation_cmd) is set to **Drop existing object and create a new one**.  This is why your tables are being dropped and recreated in SERVER B.

You will need to manually merge the existing databases into one and initialize from that source.

Alternatively, you can set the article property **Action if name is in use** to **Keep existing object unchanged**, **Delete data**, or **Truncate all data in the existing object**.  You can find this option in the Publication Properties -> Articles page.  You will need to experiment with each option to see which one meets your needs.